# kotlin fragment error NullPointerException

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-context

my complete code

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainex, container, false)

        val groupAdapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>().apply {
            spanCount = 2
        }

        recycler_view.apply {
            //error NullPointerException in this line
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(rootView.context, groupAdapter.spanCount).apply {
                spanSizeLookup = groupAdapter.spanSizeLookup
            }
            adapter = groupAdapter
        }


        var headerTab: ArrayList<mTop>
        headerTab = arguments?.getSerializable("headertab") as ArrayList<mTop>


        for (h in 0 until headerTab.size) {
            val header = headerTab.get(h).kategori

            ExpandableGroup(ExpandableHeaderItem(header), true).apply {

                for (c in 0 until headerTab[h].sub.size) {
                    val gambar = (headerTab[h].sub).get(c).gambar
                    val nama_menu = (headerTab[h].sub).get(c).nama_menu
                    add(Section(FancyItem(gambar, nama_menu)))
                }

                groupAdapter.add(this)
            }

        }
```

I'm trying to make the recyclerview display in the tablayout fragment
and an error occurred, maybe the problem comes from rootView.context

```
 layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(rootView.context, groupAdapter.spanCount).apply {
                spanSizeLookup = groupAdapter.spanSizeLookup
 }
```

thanks :)    (sorry, my english is bad)

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, of course. below

Comment: How do you init recycler_view?

Comment: Your rootView.context is normal. recycler_view is null. It looks like you use kotlin synthetic. Check if you bind proper xml file

Comment: yes, done. i use onCreateView and onViewCreated. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. this my complete fix code with separate onCreateView and onViewCreate. thanks all

```
class FragBaru : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var rv: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainex, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        rv = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

        val groupAdapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>().apply {
            spanCount = 2
        }

        rv.apply {
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(rootView.context, groupAdapter.spanCount).apply {
                spanSizeLookup = groupAdapter.spanSizeLookup
            }
            adapter = groupAdapter
        }

        var headerTab: ArrayList<mTop>
        headerTab = arguments?.getSerializable("headertab") as ArrayList<mTop>


        for (h in 0 until headerTab.size) {
            val header = headerTab.get(h).kategori

            ExpandableGroup(ExpandableHeaderItem(header), true).apply {

                for (c in 0 until headerTab[h].sub.size) {
                    val gambar = (headerTab[h].sub).get(c).gambar
                    val nama_menu = (headerTab[h].sub).get(c).nama_menu
                    add(Section(FancyItem(gambar, nama_menu)))
                }

                groupAdapter.add(this)
            }

        }
    }


    companion object {
        fun newInstance(headertab: ArrayList<mTop>): FragBaru {
            val f = FragBaru()

            val args = Bundle()
            args.putSerializable("headertab", headertab)

            f.setArguments(args)
            return f
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting LayoutManager to recyclerView before the view is created. You should do this in onViewCreated() method or in the xml file. Use onCreateView() only for inflating the view. And then use onViewCreated() for others settings you need to do to your views.

Comment: Yes, you are right. this done with use onCreateView and onViewCreate. whereas in other cases I succeeded by only using onCreateView. okey, thank you so much